# Admin metabox with custom post type dropdown option not update choosed input after saving

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, metabox

I'm trying to build a little plugin for wp that add a button to custom post type page `http://example.com/events` that have a link to another custom post type page that I can choose from a dropdown menu in admin pages.

The metabox display properly but the option choosed is not saved when I update the page.

[image: metabox dropdwon menu closed]

[image: metabox dropdwon menu closed]

this is my code:

```
class eca_metabox {

    public function __construct()
  {

        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'eca_add_meta_box' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save' ), 10, 2 );

    }

    public function eca_add_meta_box()
  {

        add_meta_box(
      'eca-meta',
          'Scegli a quale corso deve linkare questo evento',
          array(
        $this,
        'eca_meta_box_function'
      ),
          'tribe_events',
          'normal',
          'high'
    );

    }

    public function eca_meta_box_function( $post )
  {

    wp_nonce_field( 'eca_nonce_check', 'eca_nonce_check_value' );
    $mv = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ec-addons-course', true );
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object('course');
    $name = $post_type_object->name;
    $label = $post_type_object->label;
    $posts = get_posts(
      array(
        'post_type'=>           'course',
        'post_status'=>         'publish',
        'suppress_filters' =>   false,
        'posts_per_page'=>      -1,
      )
    ); ?>

    <select name="eca-addons-course" id="eca-addons-<?php echo $name; ?>">
      <option value = "" >Tutti i <?php echo strtolower( $label ); ?></option>
    <?php foreach ( $posts as $post ) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>_<?php echo preg_replace('#[ -]+#', '-' ,$post->post_title ); ?>" <?php selected( $mv, $post->ID ); ?>><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>

  <?php

  }

    public function save( $post_id )
  {

        if( !isset($_POST['eca_nonce_check_value'] ) )
            return $post_id;

        $nonce = $_POST['eca_nonce_check_value'];
        if( !wp_verify_nonce( 'eca_nonce_check_value', 'eca_nonce_check' ) )
            return $post_id;

        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
            return $post_id;

    $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

        if (!current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_post, $post_id ))
        return $post_id;

    $new_meta_value = ( isset( $_POST['ec-addons-course'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['ec-addons-course'] ) : '' );
    $mk = 'ec-addons-course';

    update_post_meta( $post->ID, $mk, $new_meta_value );
}

}

$eca_course = new eca_metabox();

add_action( 'tribe_events_single_event_after_the_content', 'ec_addons_single_course_button_link' );
function ec_addons_single_course_button_link()
{
  $output = "<a id ='courseLink' class='tribe-events-course-detail tribe-events-button' href='#' title='Vai al corso'>Vai al dettaglio del corso </a>";
  var_dump($eca_course);

    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                var course = $("' . $output . '");
                $(".tribe-events-cal-links").append(course);
            });
        </script>
    ';
}
```

On frontend side, th button display properly, but the href not work: now the page redirect itself, I want that link to url of the course that I've choosed in dropdown menu in admin metabox.

Thank for help.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Why are you saving the meta value in this format: `{post ID}_{post title escaped}` ? Why not just save the post ID? And there are other issues with your code, such as mismatched meta key - `_ec-addons-course` vs `ec-addons-course`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right about the value, in fact I've follow your hint and I've replaced it only with ID. At this moment, sadly, I'don't know why the choosed input in dropdown menu is not saved when upload the page. Can you help me to find where I'm failing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The issues with your code

1. In the `eca_meta_box_function()` function, the selected option is not being selected because the `option`'s value is not the post ID which is being used with the `selected()` function in WordPress: (wrapped for clarity)

   ```
   <option value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>_<?php echo preg_replace('#[ -]+#', '-' ,$post->post_title ); ?>" <!-- wrapped -->
     <?php selected( $mv, $post->ID ); ?>><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></option>
   ```

   so that should be: (wrapped for clarity)

   ```
   <option value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" <!-- wrapped -->
     <?php selected( $mv, $post->ID ); ?>><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></option>
   ```
2. In the `save()` function, you should capture two parameters (which WordPress passes to your function via the `save_post` hook) — 1) `$post_id` (the post ID); and 2) `$post` (the post data/object), like so:

   ```
   public function save( $post_id, $post )
   ```
3. Also in the `save()` function, you already captured the *submitted* nonce (which you store in the `$nonce` variable), but you're not using that variable:

   ```
   wp_verify_nonce( 'eca_nonce_check_value', 'eca_nonce_check' )
   ```

   and that prevents the selected option (or meta value) from being saved into the database! So change that to:

   ```
   wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'eca_nonce_check' )
   ```
4. Also in the `save()` function, you used the wrong field name — the `<select>` in the `eca_meta_box_function()` function has its `name` set to `eca-addons-course` as in `<select name="eca-addons-course"...>`. And yet, in the `save()` function, you used:

   ```
   $_POST['ec-addons-course']
   ```

   when it should really be:

   ```
   $_POST['eca-addons-course']
   ```

   that mistake also prevents the selected option from being saved, obviously!
5. Also in the `save()` function, I believe the meta key you should use is `_ec-addons-course` (which is used in the `eca_meta_box_function()` function) and *not* `ec-addons-course`:

   ```
   $mk = 'ec-addons-course';  // before; incorrect
   $mk = '_ec-addons-course'; // after; correct
   ```
6. In the `ec_addons_single_course_button_link()` function, you're *not* actually retrieving the saved meta data (and the `$eca_course` was not accessible from the function/context — you need to do `global $eca_course;` to get into that variable).

   So you can retrieve the saved meta data like so:

   ```
   $course_ID = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ec-addons-course', true );
   ```

   and use `get_permalink()` to retrieve the correct course URL address like so:

   ```
   $url = esc_url( get_permalink( $course_ID ) );
   ```

### THE CORRECTED CODE

I didn't re-indent the code (so that you could just compare it with yours, as in the current question). However, I renamed the `$mv` to `$course_ID` since that makes more meaningful..

```
class eca_metabox {

    public function __construct()
  {

        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'eca_add_meta_box' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save' ), 10, 2 );

    }

    public function eca_add_meta_box()
  {

        add_meta_box(
      'eca-meta',
          'Scegli a quale corso deve linkare questo evento',
          array(
        $this,
        'eca_meta_box_function'
      ),
          'tribe_events',
          'normal',
          'high'
    );

    }

    public function eca_meta_box_function( $post )
  {

    wp_nonce_field( 'eca_nonce_check', 'eca_nonce_check_value' );
    $course_ID = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ec-addons-course', true );
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object('course');
    $name = $post_type_object->name;
    $label = $post_type_object->label;
    $posts = get_posts(
      array(
        'post_type'=>           'course',
        'post_status'=>         'publish',
        'suppress_filters' =>   false,
        'posts_per_page'=>      -1,
      )
    ); ?>

    <select name="eca-addons-course" id="eca-addons-<?php echo $name; ?>">
      <option value = "" >Tutti i <?php echo strtolower( $label ); ?></option>
    <?php foreach ( $posts as $post ) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" <?php selected( $course_ID, $post->ID ); ?>><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>

  <?php

  }

    public function save( $post_id, $post )
  {

        if( !isset($_POST['eca_nonce_check_value'] ) )
            return $post_id;

        $nonce = $_POST['eca_nonce_check_value'];
        if( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'eca_nonce_check' ) )
            return $post_id;

        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
            return $post_id;

    $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

        if (!current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_post, $post_id ))
        return $post_id;

    $new_meta_value = ( isset( $_POST['eca-addons-course'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['eca-addons-course'] ) : '' );
    $mk = '_ec-addons-course';

    update_post_meta( $post->ID, $mk, $new_meta_value );
}

}

$eca_course = new eca_metabox();

add_action( 'tribe_events_single_event_after_the_content', 'ec_addons_single_course_button_link' );
function ec_addons_single_course_button_link()
{
  $course_ID = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ec-addons-course', true );
  $url = esc_url( get_permalink( $course_ID ) );

  $output = "<a id='courseLink' class='tribe-events-course-detail tribe-events-button' href='$url' title='Vai al corso'>Vai al dettaglio del corso </a>";

    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                var course = $("' . $output . '");
                $(".tribe-events-cal-links").append(course);
            });
        </script>
    ';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are the man. Now understand better where I was wrong. You helped me a lot. Thanks for your disponibility. Have a nice day

Comment: I'm glad it helped you @Sago. Have a nice day, too. :)